# btt in blktrace tool does not report any data in android

Tags: linux, performance, filesystems, io, block-device

I have collected trace data in file parse.bin with blktrace in android.
Then I use `btt` to parse the cellocted data as below:

**/ssd/blktrace/btt/btt -i parse.bin**

But it does not report any data. The report is as below:

```
==================== All Devices ====================

            ALL           MIN           AVG           MAX           N
--------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -----------


==================== Device Overhead ====================

       DEV |       Q2G       G2I       Q2M       I2D       D2C
---------- | --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------

==================== Device Merge Information ====================

       DEV |       #Q       #D   Ratio |   BLKmin   BLKavg   BLKmax    Total
---------- | -------- -------- ------- | -------- -------- -------- --------

==================== Device Q2Q Seek Information ====================

       DEV |          NSEEKS            MEAN          MEDIAN | MODE
---------- | --------------- --------------- --------------- | ---------------

==================== Device D2D Seek Information ====================

       DEV |          NSEEKS            MEAN          MEDIAN | MODE
---------- | --------------- --------------- --------------- | ---------------

==================== Plug Information ====================

       DEV |    # Plugs # Timer Us  | % Time Q Plugged
---------- | ---------- ----------  | ----------------

       DEV |    IOs/Unp   IOs/Unp(to)
---------- | ----------   ----------

==================== Active Requests At Q Information ====================

       DEV |  Avg Reqs @ Q
---------- | -------------

==================== I/O Active Period Information ====================

       DEV |     # Live      Avg. Act     Avg. !Act % Live
---------- | ---------- ------------- ------------- ------
---------- | ---------- ------------- ------------- ------
 Total Sys |          0   0.000000000   0.000000000   0.00
```

I run `btt` in the same way as many [examples](http://wiki.dreamrunner.org/public_html/Low_Latency_Programming/blktrace.html#:%7E:text=the%20I/O-,example,-%24%20sudo%20blktrace%20%2Dd). The input file `parse.bin` contains valid data.

So why does not `btt` print any data?

Comment: What are you system's details? What do you expect BTT to return? What is the valid data in parse.bin? Your question appears to need a lot more information. Please edit it to  improve it.